# Show that the function $||u|| = \sqrt{2|u_1|^2+5|u_2|^2}$ is a norm on $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm given: Let $V$ be the real vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $u = [u_1 \, u_2]^T \in V$. Show that the function $||u|| = \sqrt{2|u_1|^2+5|u_2|^2}$ is a norm on $V$. Then, determine whether this norm is derived from an inner product. If so, what is the inner product?

After many attempts, I'm having trouble (a) proving that this function satisfies the Triangle Inequality property of norms (i.e. that $||u+v|| \leq ||u|| + ||v||$), and (b) determining the inner product this norm is derived from. Any help getting unstuck would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\|.\|'$ is the usual norm then $\|(u,v)\|=\|(\sqrt 2, \sqrt 5v)\|'$. it should be easy to see from this triangle inequality for $\|(u,v)\|'$ gives triangle inequality for $\|(u,v)\|$. This inner norm is derived form the inner product $ \langle (u,v) (u',v') \rangle= \langle (\sqrt 2 u, \sqrt 5v), (\sqrt 2 u, \sqrt 5v) \rangle'$ where the prime is used to denote the usual inner product.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me see it!